# Property of inner product

Tags: matrices, inner-products

Let $h$ be the standard Hermitian product in $\mathbb{C}^n$, that is:

$$h(x, y) = \sum_{j=1}^n x^j\overline{y}^j$$

How can I prove the following property?

$$h(Ax, y) = h(x, \overline{A}^ty)$$

for every complex matrix A of order $n\times n$ whose and every $x, y\in\mathbb{C}^n$. I've tried the obvious, developing both sides of the previous equality, but I don't get the same result.

Comment: View elements of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as $n\times 1$ matrices and write $h(x,y) = \overline{y}^t\cdot x$.

Comment: Have you tried expanding the matrix multiplication as well? That should give you your answer quite quickly

Comment: @John I have tried that, but I still have the conjugate of the elements of the matrix on the right, and that doesn't appear that way on the left...

Comment: @WildFeather You're forgetting that the entire second element gets conjugated in the definition of $h$. Thus the elements of $A$ get conjugated twice when you insert and calculate.

Comment: @Arthur Oh wow, I feel so stupid now. That was it. I was just missing that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = (a_{ij})$. Then:
$$
h(Ax,y) = \sum_{j=1}^n (Ax)_j \overline y_j = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}x_i\right)\overline y_j = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ji}x_i\overline y_j \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ji}\overline{y_j}\right)= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \overline{\overline{a_{ji}}y_j}\right)\\= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\overline{\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \overline{a_{ji}}y_j\right)} = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\overline{\left(\overline{A^t}y\right)}_i= h(x,\overline{A^t}y)
$$

Comment: Thank you, that's a short and elegant proof!

Comment: You are welcome!